# Build an RPM dependency chain without installing dependencies on build host

Tags: dependency-management, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to set up an RPM builder that will compile all the dependent binaries and executable of my project.

The dependency looks a bit like this:

```
MainProject.rpm | depends on:
    |
    +-- subProject1.rpm | depends on:
    |       |
    |       +-- subProject2.rpm
    |
    +-- subProject2.rpm
```

I'm generating all these RPMs in this order:

```
-build rpm for subProject2
-install subProject2 RPM in System

-build rpm for subProject1 
-install subProject1 RPM in System

-build rpm for subProject3
-install subProject3 RPM in System

-build rpm for MainProject
```

All my spec files are producing suitable RPMs, at the cost of myself having to install on my machine the subProject2.rpm before attempting to `rpmbuild` `subProject1`.
Same goes for the mainProject.rpm : if I want to build it, I have to install all the RPMs it depends on.

I feel like this way of doing things is very bad, because I'm installing these RPMs in my builder's filesystem.

Is there an RPMbuild option to, say, deploy the RPM dependency in a chroot-like environment to build another one? I think if there exists such thing, it also needs to take in account the RPATH.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a bad thing if your build environment is not controlled as far as I'm concerned. Assuming you have a controlled, repeatable build process doing things this way should be fine I believe.

That being said the answer to your actual question is to do what Fedora/etc. are doing and use [Koji](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji) or at least the underlying chroot-related piece called [Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock).

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using the '--root' option.  Use it with both the 'rpm' command and for the 'rpmbuild' command.  With this option, all the rpm constraints and actions will be in relation to this 'chroot-like' environment.  It must be a fully qualified path.
Ex:

```
rpmbuild --root /home/user/master-project/rpmroot
```

There are at least three major implications for this:

1) you must initialize an rpm database in this area before you can use it for other commands;

```
rpm --initdb --root /home/user/master-project/rpmroot
```

2) all dependencies in the alternate root must be met by some other package in the alternate root.  this can get difficult if, in your case for example, 'MainProject' depends on standard libraries.

3) as you alluded, compilers/linkers must also know about the alternate root.
Ex:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/master-project/rpmroot/usr/lib
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/user/master-project/rpmroot/usr/include
```

hope this helps.